# Apache IoTDB cannot delete a time series automatically created by Session

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

Session's write interfaces such as insertTablet and insertRecords interface do not do format checking for sequences, and sequences that do not conform to naming conventions are still created automatically.
These sequences cannot be deleted through the Cli because the Cli use the SQL interface and does not allow you to write sequence paths that do not conform to the specification.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOmjy.png)

Answer (score 1):

Welcome BesonChou. Could you try to escape the names (with the dots in it) in the CLI via double ticks (`"`) then shou yould be able to delete the timeseries there, e.g.

```
DELETE TIMESERIES root.brige-ysg."82001..1501".v
```

See here in the Section "Layer Names" for more details: http://iotdb.apache.org/UserGuide/Master/Data-Concept/Data-Model-and-Terminology.html

> Single quotes are not allowed in the path. If you want to use special
> characters such as "." in LayerName, use double quotes. For example,
> root.sg."d.1"."s.1".
>
> The characters supported in LayerName without double quotes are as
> below:
>
> ```
> Chinese characters '\u2E80' to '\u9FFF'
> '+', '&', '%', '$', '#', '@', '/', '_', '-', ':'
> 'A' to 'Z', 'a' to 'z', '0' to '9'
> '[', ']' (eg. 's[1', 's[1]', s[ab]')
> ```
>
> '-' and ':' cannot be the first character. '+' cannot use alone.